# Convert JPanel into png or other image file

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel that consists of a lot of JLabels. So there is no paint at all, just JLabels with different background colors and such. The JPanel is visible.

How can I convert this JPanel to an image file? The image file would be a picture of the JPanel exactly as it appears on the screen.

(Ideally, the program would create a .png, and save it to the same folder that the program is in or even a different folder chosen by the user.)

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

---- It's Cherie again, unregistered so I couldn't get back into my account to choose stas's answer as the answer. This is why I'm not replying... anyway, thank you for your help. Cherie

Comment: Well, programmatically? The user clicks a button, and the image is created and saved.

Answer (score 4):

[Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) will choose the best way to create the image.

```
BufferedImage bi = ScreenImage.createImage(panel);
ScreenImage.writeImage(bi, "panel.png");
```

Comment: @Cherie, So what happened when you actually tried the code? It takes two lines of code, one to create the image and the second to save it.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(panel.getLocationOnScreen().x, panel.getLocationOnScreen().y, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
```

You create a file like this:

```
File file = new File("fileName.png");
if (!file.exists())file.createNewFile();
```

please select my answer as correct if i answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks. This should work. Yet, er, how do I create a new file? I'm a little confused about how to File class works, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The java.awt.Robot classes can take a screen dump which you can then put where you need it for later.

Comment: I think Robots are what I am looking for. Thank you.